# Passing authorization code to Python Notebook

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, databricks

As I am trying to connect to Google's BigQuery environment from a Python notebook using the google.cloud library, the response from the server is to visit a link that generates a code and to "Enter the authorization code:" . However, as this response is just text, I do not know how to pass the code back to the server response. I am running this notebook in a Databricks environment.

Does anyone know how I can push this code back to the server and complete the authorization?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnn't look like you are using the correct . The flow which you mentioned will work on a UI not not with any automation . I suggest you to share more dtails here and also check for more documenataion on the same .